# How to add conditional left or inner join based on parameter in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to add conditional  left or inner join based on parameter in my select statement.

For example :

I have TableA and TableB, and I have a parameter called @test,

I wanna do something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
IF(@test ='')
 INNER JOIN TableB
ELSE
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
```

IS that possible in SQL Server 2012 ?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the kind of the `JOIN` based on a parameter, but you can filter out the rows with `NULL`s in an outer join.

Suppose that `TableB` is joined to `TableA` on `b.a_id = a.id`. Then you could write this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b
             ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE @test != '' OR b.a_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: So Dynamic SQL is the solution as mentioned by Gordon Linoff ?

Comment: @Mohammadjouhari Dynamic SQL is *a* solution, not *the* solution. Both our answers are very much identical, suggesting to add a conditional `WHERE` filter that turns an outer join into an inner join.

Comment: Thanks for both of you for the answers. I appreciate it.

Comment: Unless you find that the two types of joins have wildly difference performance characteristics, there would be no need to go with dynamic SQL for this.  The performance considerations could exist, but are unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly (except using dynamic SQL), but you can do this in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TableB
     ON . . .
WHERE (@test = '' and TableB.id is not null) or (@test <> '')
```